# Struts hibernate update hybrid example

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

I want to update database record using same session and session Target

Please help me to handle the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use session.merge(Object name) method.

ex:

```
User u1 = new User("Bill");
u1.setFavoriteColor("blue");
session.save(u1);
User u2 = new User("Bill");
u2.setFavoriteColor("red");
u2 = session.merge(u2);
```